# VBA - .Click in IE only works every few attempts

Tags: vba, excel, onclick

Note: I posted the same question on VBA Express a few days ago but have not been able to solve this problem. Don't want to cause any double work.

I am trying to go to a site and play a soundbite with an onclick reference. I am having trouble getting the soundbite to play every time with my code. It will play every few times though which is the strange thing to me. I can't use getelementbyid because I plan to search through several links and won't know what the id is beforehand. Any ideas on how to get the soundbite to play every time? Thank you.

```
Sub Encore()

    Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer     
    Dim sURL As String 

    sURL = "http://forvo.com"                

    Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer 

    oBrowser.Silent = True 
    oBrowser.navigate sURL 
    oBrowser.Visible = True 

    Do While oBrowser.Busy: DoEvents: Loop 

    oBrowser.navigate "http://forvo.com/search/encore/fr" 
    Do While oBrowser.Busy: DoEvents: Loop 
    oBrowser.document.getElementsByClassName("play")(0).Click 

End sub
```

Another attempt:

```
Sub Encore()

    Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer     
    Dim div As HTMLDivElement
    Dim sURL As String 

    sURL = "http://forvo.com"                

    Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer 

    oBrowser.Silent = True 
    oBrowser.navigate sURL 
    oBrowser.Visible = True 

    Do While oBrowser.Busy: DoEvents: Loop 

    oBrowser.navigate "http://forvo.com/search/encore/fr" 
    Do While oBrowser.Busy: DoEvents: Loop 
    Set div = oBrowser.document.getElementsByClassName("play")(0)
    div.FireEvent "onclick"

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Get elements by tag name of "a" and do the loop statement until the  element name find, if name found and click the link.

You use any name of link element in the for loop

```
Sub Encore()
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim mydoc As HTMLDocument

    Dim sURL As String

    sURL = "http://forvo.com"

    Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer

    oBrowser.Silent = True
    oBrowser.navigate sURL
    oBrowser.Visible = True

    Do While oBrowser.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    oBrowser.navigate "http://forvo.com/search/encore/fr"
    Do While oBrowser.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Set mydoc = oBrowser.document


    Set div = mydoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each link In div
            Debug.Print link.Text
            If link.Text = "encore" Then
            link.Click
            Exit For
           End If
    Next link


Set div = mydoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
        For Each link In div
                Debug.Print link.Text
                If link.Text = "encore pronunciation" Then
                link.Click
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
                link.Click

                Exit For
               End If
        Next link


   End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am not trying to click on the href link. I am trying to click on the onclick reference in the code that will play the sound file.        <a title="Listen encore pronunciation" class="play" id="play_155156" onclick="Play(155156,'ODk3OTkyMi80OS84OTc5OTIyXzQ5XzQwNjk3MV8xLm1wMw==','ODk3OTkyMi80OS84OTc5OTIyXzQ5XzQwNjk3MV8xLm9nZw==',false,'Mi91LzJ1Xzg5Nzk5MjJfNDlfNDA2OTcxXzEubXAz','Mi91LzJ1Xzg5Nzk5MjJfNDlfNDA2OTcxXzEub2dn','h');return false;" href="http://forvo.com/word/encore/#fr" rel="nofollow">encore pronunciation</a>

Comment: @b.hill2387 Try link.text "encore pronunciation" instead of "encore"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kathir for your help. I figured out a workaround to my issues. It is probably not the cleanest solution, but it works. The class name would change from "play" to "play loading" after clicked. Sometimes the sound would play, but when it didn't the class name stuck in "play loading. So I just set a For loop to check for the "play loading" class name and exit the loop if it didn't exist.

Sub Encore()

```
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim sURL As String
Dim a As Integer

sURL = "http://forvo.com"

On Error Resume Next
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer

oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do While oBrowser.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

oBrowser.navigate "http://forvo.com/search/encore/fr"
Do While oBrowser.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

For a = 0 To 50
    oBrowser.document.getElementsByClassName("play")(0).Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    If oBrowser.document.getElementsByClassName("play loading")(0).innerText = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next a

a = 0
```

End Sub